# React native crashes in xcode 11.6

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I tried to build app in xcode 11.6, I got this exception and I have no idea where to look for a solution:
**Exception NSException *   "data parameter is nil" 0x00006000014d7960.**

And this is the code that's appear:

```js
DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block); //Exception in this line: Thread 2: Exception: "data parameter is nil"
    } else {
        dispatch_compiler_barrier();
    }
    DISPATCH_COMPILER_CAN_ASSUME(*predicate == ~0l);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this? Facing the same problem with random crashes.

Comment: @Edinho Rodrigues Were you able to get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is absolutely irrelevant now, but I was facing the same problem and it turned out that within the block that's being passed to `dispatch_once`, an exception was thrown and `libdispatch` in such case aborts the app.

Like this:

```
#undef _dispatch_client_callout
void
_dispatch_client_callout(void *ctxt, dispatch_function_t f)
{
    @try {
        return f(ctxt);
    }
    @catch (...) {
        objc_terminate();
    }
}
```

So whoever is facing similar problems, check your block and exceptions that it might throw.